# Return the index for the maximum value

Tags: c++

I have written the following which gets the index value for the maximum number.

```
int TravellingSalesMan::getMaximum(double *arr){
    double temp = arr[0];
    int iterator = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        if(arr[i] > temp){
            iterator = i;
        }
    }
    return iterator;
}
```

But the output keeps stepping into the conditional statement and keeps printing out 29. I am not sure why this is happening

I also tried using max_element() but with no luck

**EDIT**

The above function is invoked as following

```
static unsigned int chromosome = 30;
double value[chromosome]

for(int i = 0; i < chromosomes; i++){
    value[i] = estimateFitness(currPopultaion[i]);
}
int best = 0;
best = getMaximum(value);
cout<<best<<endl; // this just prints out 29
```

Comment: voted to close as lacking reproducible example

Comment: "keeps printing out 29" - there is nothing in this code that generates any output whatsoever. How about a [minimal, **complete**, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that produces the problem you're describing? And fyi, `temp = arr[i]` had better be in there somewhere, or all you're doing is comparing everything to whatever is in `arr[0]`. My crystal ball tells me `arr[29]` is just that.

Comment: First of all, your use of the Variable name **iterator** is very very wrong. Its not used for iteration over the list. Why create confusion? Best to use something like MaxIndex or something like that.

Comment: And why start from i=0? Your temp value is arr[0], so here is no use of checking with first element again. Start from i=1!

Comment: That *still* isn't a minimal **COMPLETE** example, and see my prior comment. That last sentence is important. `temp` is worthless in that loop. The if-case should be `if(arr[i] > arr[iterator])` and `temp` should be removed entirely. And if that is indeed the context from which it is called, my prior comment [in your prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42463818/making-use-of-max-element) stands. Why do this *at all* ? Just track the largest-element index in your prior loop.

Comment: What @WhozCraig means by minimal COMPLETE example is for you to show the values that you are passing into the `arr[]` and print the output you got.

Comment: If that is not homework, [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) has you covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I didn't plan on writing the answer, but I just saw too many logical mistakes in the code for me to write in the comments section!

- > First of all, your use of the variable name `iterator` is very
  >   wrong. It's not used for iteration over the list. Why create confusion. Best to use something like `max_index` or something like that.
- > Why start from `i=0`? Your temp value is `arr[0]`, so there is no use. of checking with first element again. Start from i=1!
- > `temp` is pointless in that function. The maximum index should initially be `0`, and set to `i` if ever there is some `arr[i]` that is greater than `arr[max_index]`.
- > Passing the length separately to the function is better coding as it makes the code more clearer.
- > The content in `arr` is not modified, and as such better safe than sorry: make the pointer `const`.

---

Re-writing the code, it should be:

```
int TravellingSalesMan::getMaximum(const double *arr,int len)
{
    int max_index = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] > arr[max_index])
            max_index = i;
    }
    return max_index;
}
```

Worth noting, but unchanged in the code above, `len`, `i`, and the function result should *all* be an unsigned integer type. There is no reason, to allow signed integer indexing, so make it a warning-condition from the caller if they do so by hard-specifying `unsigned` or just `size_t` as the indexing variable types.

Comment: All reasonable crtic points except that pointlessness of temp in real life. There is a good chance for temp residing in a faster memory area than arr[x], it may even be a CPU-register. In the context of the questioners example it is indeed pointless as he forgot to adjust temp, when finding a new maximum. To remain in your critics line that 'temp' should of course be some thing like 'max_val' :)

Comment: The edit on the use of `temp` was proposed by @WhozCraig. Am going to remain a by-stander for this discussion (and learn a thing or two from where this is headed, by the looks of it) :D

Answer (score 2):

You should be assigning a new value to `temp` when you find a new maximum.

```
int TravellingSalesMan::getMaximum(double *arr){
    double temp = arr[0];
    int iterator = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        if(arr[i] > temp){
            iterator = i;
            temp = arr[i];  // this was missing
        }
    }
    return iterator;
}
```

Without this you are finding the largest index of a value greater than the value at index zero.

A much better solution is to simply use [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) instead.  Pointers can be used as iterators in most (if not all) algorithms requiring iterators.

```
#include <algorithm>

static unsigned int chromosomes = 30;
double value[chromosomes];
for (int i=0; i<chromosomes; ++i) {
    value[I] = estimate_fitness(current_population[i]);
}

double *max_elm = std::max_element(&value[0], &value[chromosomes]);
int best = int(max_elm - &value[0]);
std::cout << best << std::endl;
```